# CPU frequency in KVM vps

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, central-processing-unit, frequency

Is it possible to display CPU max and min frequency in a KVM vps using Libvirt on server ?
It only shows CPU mhz in vps and not max and min mhz as seen on server in lscpu command output.

Comment: which CPU are you using on the VM?

Comment: AFAIK CPU tuning is done from the hypervisor and not  from within the guest, so it does not seem surprising that the guest reports a fixed rather than adjustable frequency

Comment: host-model and passthrough options have not helped for displaying max and min mhz within vps.
How can it be verified that its actually using the max limit in vps ?